# How to add line to the file without delete

Tags: php, file, append, line

I want to write a line to the end of the file.

My code is:

```
$myFile = "serialkey.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$space = "\r\n";

$stringData = "my new data";
fwrite($fh, $stringData.$space);

fclose($fh);
```

But when I used this code it deleted all the file and replace "my new data", I want it will not delete my file and append my data to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it set to write instead of append in

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
```

It should be

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To insert text without over-writing the end of the file, you'll have to open it for appending ([`a+` rather than `w`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php))

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a+');
```